# Perl Array sum similar elements

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key, duplicates

I have an array which consists of both strings and numbers. I want to sum those numbers which has similar string value. Please help!!

INFILE:

```
aggr3 350.01000213623
aggr3 1228.79999923706
aggr5 250
aggr3 1536
aggr3 690.01000213623
aggr3 1587.20000076294
aggr9 550.01000213623
aggr3 1228
aggr5 905
aggr5 100
```

Required output

```
aggr3 5391
aggr5 1255
aggr9 550
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this perhaps?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = <DATA>;
my %data;
$data{$_->[0]} += $_->[1] for map [ split ], @data;

print "$_ $data{$_}\n" for sort keys %data;

__DATA__
aggr3 350.01000213623
aggr3 1228.79999923706
aggr5 250
aggr3 1536
aggr3 690.01000213623
aggr3 1587.20000076294
aggr9 550.01000213623
aggr3 1228
aggr5 905
aggr5 100
```

**output**

```
aggr3 6620.02000427246
aggr5 1255
aggr9 550.01000213623
```

Comment: +1 for that collecting one-liner. ) I've almost forgotten how concise Perl can be.

Comment: The only sigil you're missing is `*data`, else the script would be a good test of one's understanding of `perlreftut` :)

Comment: @mpapec: The question says, *"I have an `array` which consists of both strings and numbers"*

Answer (score 2):

Usually, if you want to group some data in Perl, you [use hashes](http://www.perl.com/pub/2006/11/02/all-about-hashes.html). Keys of these hashes correspond to a grouping criteria, and values serve as accumulators (it can be a simple number, as in this case, or an array of numbers waiting to be processed later).

Here's one way to do it:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# this hash will hold all the cumulatives
my %sums;

# here we scan the source, line by line
# each line is split to key and value
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($label, $value) = split;

  # this line uses the auto-vivification Perl feature:
  # if there's no corresponding item in %sums hash, it'll be created (with 0 value)
  $sums{$label} += $value;
}

# here we process the resulting hash:
for my $key (sort keys %sums) {
  print $key, ' ', $sums{$key}, "\n";
}
__DATA__
aggr3 350.01000213623
aggr3 1228.79999923706
aggr5 250
aggr3 1536
aggr3 690.01000213623
aggr3 1587.20000076294
aggr9 550.01000213623
aggr3 1228
aggr5 905
aggr5 100
```

[Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/hqwUP6QS).

Comment: Here's the one-liner version: `perl -nalwe '$a{$F[0]} += $F[1]; }{ print "$_ $a{$_}" for keys %a'`